# How to retrieve informations from C++ header file

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to analyze a cpp header file for my toy project.

```cpp
// header file
namespace X
{
    class A
    {
    private:
        int a;
        double b;

    public:
        int foo(Some, Other);
    }
}
```

with this header file, I want to read this code file and convert this into C# code, something like

```cs
class Class
{
    string NameSpace; // would be "X"
    string ClassName; // would be "A"

    List<Function> Functions;
    List<Field> Fields;
}

class Function
{
    bool IsPublic; // would be true
    string Name; // would be "foo"
    string ReturnType; // would be "int"
    List<string> ParamType; // would be {"Some", "Other"}
}

class Field
{
    bool IsPublic;
    string Name;
    string Type;
}
```

Of course the structure of class may be changed for proper operation, but the main concept would not change. Due to my lack of background knowledge, writing my own parser would be the final solution :(

Would you please give me any suggestions?

Comment: If Windows, you can use the DIA SDK to parse the PDB file generated by the VS compiler.

Comment: if you want to parse a C++ header, you need a parser, no way around that.

Comment: C++ is one of the most complicated languages on the planet, if you want to do this, you will have to use existing tooling like LLVM and Clang.

Comment: my suggestion would be to generate both the C++ and the C# from some simpler representation. Generating C++ code is way simpler than parsing it, because you only need a tiny subset of all allowed grammar